# problem with converting a entity to json using jms_serializer - Symfony 4

Tags: json, symfony, entity, symfony4, jms-serializer

i'm trying to make an api to return a json with symfony 4 
i create a entity and it's work fine but it do not convert data for database to json 
so the Serializer from "Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer" give me error

```
 serialization for the format json is not supported
```

so i tried the Jms_Serializer but in the official website they work with a old version of symfony 
i installed the bundle with

```
composer require jms/serializer-bundle
```

this the code in controller

```
class ProduitsController extends AbstractController
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/api/produits/cuisine")
         */
        public function index()
        {
            $dc = $this->getDoctrine();

            $Produits=$dc->getRepository(Article::class)->findAll();

            $data= $this->get('jms_serializer')->serialize($Produits,'json');

            return new JsonResponse($data);

        }
    }
```

i got this error : `ServiceNotFoundException`

```
Service "jms_serializer" not found: even though it exists in the app's 
container, the container inside "App\Controller\ProduitsController" is a
 smaller service locator that only knows about the "doctrine", "form.factory",
 "http_kernel", "parameter_bag", "request_stack", "router", 
"security.authorization_checker", "security.csrf.token_manager", 
"security.token_storage", "serializer", "session" and "twig" services. Try
 using dependency injection instead
```

a simple json_encode() to the result 
give me a empty json

Comment: Which Symfony version do you really use? Why don't you use autowiring instead of manually requesting the service, just as the error message tells you?

Comment: Symfony version 4

Comment: There are a lot of Symfony versions which start with 4. And what about my second question?

Comment: check if the bundle exist on **config/bundles.php**

Comment: Additionally, what makes you think that https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer does not support current Symfony versions? That's the very package that is installed when using the bundle you are referencing

Comment: i install the last version of Symfony

Comment: and it's ok it's work

Comment: sorry but in the official website they didn't explain that we don't need to add the bundle in the last version of symfony
i'm a beginner ok
but they need to explain for beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok it work fine 
the problem was with the class AbstractController
i change it to Controller

```
class ProduitsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/api/produits/cuisine")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $dc = $this->getDoctrine();
        $Produits=$dc->getRepository(Article::class)->findAll();
        $data= $this->get('jms_serializer')->serialize($Produits,'json');

        return new JsonResponse($data);

    }
}
```